# Very simple time Complexity question

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

if I have a function: 8x+5y+20z=n
I suppose to use exhaustive search to find all possible solutions of x,y,z for the number n. the possible range to search for x,y,z are [0,n/8] [0,n/5] and [0,n/20] respectively, If I use nested for loops,then my time complexity is O(n^3/8*5*20) right?

I was poorly introduced to the Analysis of algorithm yesterday by some one doesn't speak plain English....

please give some advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will typically omit constants in asymptotic notation... so O(n^3). Assuming that you're just looking for integer solutions (for given n), your complexity is correct, assuming that you don't try anything too fancy to prune the search space (i.e., you check the entire intervals).

Answer (score 1):

You can lower drastically the calculation time by putting some conditions :

- Try only for x and y -> z= (n - 8x - 5y)/20
- n and y have same parity
- if n is a multiple of 5 equivalent to x is a multiple of 5
- etc...